# Chrome Extension: Hide All İmages And Svges

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, manifest

İ am trying to hide/delete all images in website by coding extension.
First step my code is:

```js
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var svges = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
for(i=0;i<images.length+svges.length;i++){
 if(images.length>0){
    images[i].style.display="none";
    }
    if(svges.length>0){
    svges[i].style.display="none";
    }
}
```

Then when i test my code i can see images when page loading. İ search that at google then i find:
`"run_at": "document_start"`

After that i test my code again but now i saw "undefined" error at console.

Finally my code is:

```
function hide(){
var images = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
var svges = document.getElementsByTagName('svg');
if(images.length>0){
for(i=0;i<images.length;i++){
    images[i].style.display="none";
}
}
if(svges.length>0){
for(i=0;i<svges.length;i++){
    svges[i].style.display="none";
}
}
}

myVar = setInterval(hide, 1);
```

Now i dont see images while page loading and loaded and loaded + request.

But that is i think ridicilous solution... İ dont want to set interval because that is makes tired pc...

How can i hide image while page loading and loaded and loaded + request(google scroll down that makes + requests to show images) ?

Can manifest.json handle it or can javascript handle it by not tiring pc ? How ?

Comment: this `i<images.length+svges.length` should be `i<images.length` in your second code snippet.

Comment: You are right that is my attention error thanks :)